# How to Convert Object[] array into ObservableCollection<Class> in WPF?

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid.I binded ObservableCollection to DataGrid.I added paging to it.
For it I converted ObservationCollection into DataTable.

My code is as

```
 ObservableCollection<RiskSettings> riskCollection = new ObservableCollection<RiskSettings>();

 grdRiskAlerts.DataContext = riskCollection;
            dTable = ToDataTable(riskCollection);
            object[] obj = gridPaging.CustomPaging(dTable, (int)DataGridPaging.PagingMode.First);
            grdRiskAlerts.ItemsSource = (DataView)obj[0];
            txtDispRecs.Text = obj[1].ToString();
            txtNumOfPages.Text = obj[2].ToString();
            txtTotalRecs.Text = "Total : " + dTable.Rows.Count;
            if (dTable.Rows.Count <= recPerPage)
            {
                brdPaging.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else
                brdPaging.IsEnabled = true;
```

My Class name is RiskSettings.
When i right Click on selected row,did operation Type Casting problem is arising.
So i need to bind Datagrid with class instead of (DataView)obj[0]
How to do it?
I tried it,But unable to find solution
Can any help on this?
Thanks in advance,
Ramki.